# How to access child template in reusable component in Angular 8/9/10/11

Tags: angular, datatable, parent-child, custom-component, code-reuse

I have created common component which will render data in table format.

**data-table.component.ts** (this is reusable component, can be used by any child component)

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'data-table',
      templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
    })
    export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
         //wanted to access child here(or inside any method in this class) to set the width of each <td> from child
      //wanted to access #rowTemplate children from child for all 3 <td> 
      }
setColumnWidth(width: string = "") {
    if (width != "") {
      return 'width:' + width;
    }
  }
    }
```

**data-table.component.html**

```
<table style="width:100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let c of columns" style="{{setColumnWidth(c.width)}}">
            {{c.fieldTitle}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowTemplate"></ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**resource-updates.component.ts** (this is child component)

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'resource-updates',
      templateUrl: './resource-updates.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./resource-updates.component.css']
    })
    export class ResourceUpdatesComponent implements OnInit {
      columns: Column[] = [];
      rows: any[] = [];
     
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        //Preparing list for columns
        this.columns.push(new Column({ fieldName: 'Id', fieldTitle: 'Id', isSortable: false, width: '5%' }));
        this.columns.push(new Column({ fieldName: 'Title', fieldTitle: 'Title', width: '60%' }));
        this.columns.push(new Column({ fieldName: 'Type', fieldTitle: 'Type', width: '35%' }));
      
       //Preparing list for rows
       this.rows = [
{"id":5,"title":"Air Gas Guideline","type":"PPT"},
{"id":6,"title":"Air Pollution User Reference","type":"Website"},
{"id":18,"title":"Avian Influenza (H7N9) User Reference","type":"Website"},
{"id":12,"title":"Avian Influenza (H7N9) for high risk","type":"PPT"},
{"id":11,"title":"Avian Influenza (H7N9) for normal","type":"PPT"}
];
      }
    }
```

**resource-updates.component.html** (wanted to set width of 3  below, in Parent (common component) from columns.width property)

```
  <ng-template #rowTemplate>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of rows">
      <td>{{r.id}}</td>
      <td>{{r.title}}</td>
      <td>{{r.type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <data-table [columns]="columns" [rowTemplate]="rowTemplate"></data-table>
```

Can any body help to access #rowTemplate children element  for setting up width from columns[0].width and respectively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not understanding wrong, you want to access to child component's ng-template from parent component? If it is, this is the case that I used before when create data-table controls.

1. You can create a directive class with TemplateRef in it:

```js
import { Directive, ContentChild, TemplateRef, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Directive({ selector: "np-column" })
export class NpColumnDirective {
      @Input() name: string;
      @ContentChild(TemplateRef) cellTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
      constructor() { }
}
```

2. Then in your parent compoent access it using:

`@ContentChildren(NpColumnDirective) columnComponents: QueryList<NpColumnDirective>;`

Here is the whole code I used for creating data-table, just for your reference:
[datatable demo](https://github.com/KevinZhang19870314/pluto-ui/blob/master/projects/ngx-pluto/src/lib/table/column.directive.ts)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, your understanding is correct. let me verify what you said and how to implement.

Comment: Can you explain how to access NpColumnDirective in child and parent. Your help is highly appreciated... as i am new in Angular. I looked in your code but couldn't help me to resolve my issue due to my limit knowledge!

Comment: NpColumnDirective is act as a child role, and TableComponent is act as parent role.  And this is the place we are access child in TableComponent template,         <span *ngIf="!column.isCheckbox" [style.flex]="'0 1 ' + column.width">
          <ng-container *ngIf="!column.template">{{ row[column.headerName] }}</ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="column.template">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="column.template; context: { row: row }">
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </span>

Comment: There is a example use for data-table, https://github.com/KevinZhang19870314/pluto-ui/blob/master/src/app/sample/table/table.component.html

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Zhang for sharing the link but still i am not understand how to use it. I don't see any documentation in your code. It would be great if you can provide more information.

Comment: Can you share example how to use your plugin? I mean how i can assign dataset and row template?

Comment: This is the online demo and doc: https://kevinzhang19870314.github.io/pluto-ui/ https://kevinzhang19870314.github.io/pluto-ui/doc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the `@ContentChild` and add `@Input()` annotation to the columns variable in your `DataTableComponent` (included the *Column* interface which wasn't in your question):

```js
export interface Column {
  fieldName: string;
  fieldTitle: string;
  isSortable?: boolean;
  width?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() columns: Column[] = [];

  @ContentChild('rowTemplate') rowTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

The template of the `DataTableComponent` should look like the following:

```js
<table style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let c of columns" [ngStyle]="{ width: c.width }">
        {{c.fieldTitle}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowTemplate"></ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally the `ResourceUpdatesComponent` template:

```js
<app-data-table [columns]="columns">
  <ng-template #rowTemplate>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of rows">
      <td>{{r.id}}</td>
      <td>{{r.title}}</td>
      <td>{{r.type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</app-data-table>
```

**[Uploaded the working Angular project code to Github](https://github.com/sbarbat/angular-contentchild-use)**

There is a nice article explaining how `@ContentChild` works: *[Understanding ViewChildren, ContentChildren, and QueryList in Angular](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e)*

---

**Note that removed the `setColumnWidth()` function and made use of `ngStyle`**, "that will be called every time the Angular change detection runs", see *[Why you should never use function calls in Angular template expressions](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)*